# Saving player data and status

Tags: android, persistence

I made an android game and I want to know how to save player data such as money, level reached, etc. I think that XML is not a really convenient way to do this. Is there any good way to do this? Does android provide some method to save the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database is probably overkill for the type of data you need to track. I would suggest using Android's SharedPreferences APIs. [See here for a tutorial](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html).

Here's an [official overview of Android data persistence](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) methods including SharedPreferences and SQLite.

Check out the [getStringSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) API for storage of arrays/collections.

For non-existent vals for the string set:

> Returns the preference values if they
>   exist, or defValues. Throws
>   ClassCastException if there is a
>   preference with this name that is not
>   a Set.

For non-existent value data such as string, bool, float etc.:

> Returns the preference value if it
>   exists, or defValue. Throws
>   ClassCastException if there is a
>   preference with this name that is not
>   a String.

Comment: Saving the state of a game can be quite alot of data. But i get your point :-) Good addition.

Comment: naaah not that much. just a single instance with money, points, etc . database is overkill is true :)

Comment: anyway this is great. very convenient

Comment: ah one more question before I click on the answered button. how is there's no data yet in the shared preference? will it return an error or something?

Comment: and how about array of values?? like maybe list of upgrades or items?

Comment: It's map system so you should just get a null or default value. In any case use a try/catch. The shared preferences APIs only support basic data types such as bools, ints and strings. But it does support a set which you can use to store array: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)

Comment: Please see the updated answer which now covers the additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SQlite database](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html). ( [Data storage on developers.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) )

Here is a tutorial that shows the functionality:
http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-simple-but-persistent-data-storage/