# Android saving player's data

Tags: android, save, google-play-games

In my game I want to sync player's current progress to some cloud. I decided to use **Google Saved Games API**, which works nice, it saves data locally when offline and syncs it with user's google drive when online. But these savings last a bit longer and I'm saving frequently, I don't want to loose any player's progress. I decided to use `SharedPreferences`, I know they aren't recomended because they are just xml files and root can access them and change data so I'm using [encrypted SharedPreferences](https://github.com/sveinungkb/encrypted-userprefs) in order to make it more difficut to modify it. Now the question is, is it a good way to achieve saving? Should I just sometimes pick these `SharedPreferences` data and send it to player's google drive via Saved Games API? Or any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to see the data storage options. I suggest using [SharePreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store private primitive data in key-value pairs. From this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606152/saving-player-data-and-status), check the [getStringSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) API for storage of arrays/collections if it helps.

> For non-existent vals for the string set:
>
> > Returns the preference values if they exist, or defValues. Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not
> >     a Set.
>
> For non-existent value data such as string, bool, float etc.:
>
> > Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not
> >     a String.

You can also check these links:

- [Shared Preferences | Android Developer Tutorial (Part 13)](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)
- [Adding Saved Games to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames)
- [Saving Data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)

Hope this helps!